# WL.SimpleDialog change background color

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I wanted to change the default black color of WL.SimpleDialog.show in IBM worklight to red and other colors with specifying color codes, is there a way to achieve this, if not can any one share the links to customize a loading dialog in IBM WL.

Thanks
djrecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worklight does not provide the ability to customize the background used for `WL.SimpleDialog`.

What you can do, is create a dialog of your own, where you will then have complete control over it.

- You could find some library online that creates such a dialog via JavaScript, for example jQuery Mobile, or
- You could find/implement it via native code. If you choose to implement it via native code, you will need to do so [via a Cordova plug-in](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova) for Worklight.

For those building an application for the Mobile Web, Desktop Web Browser or BlackBerry 6/7 environments, these environments use a "web busy indicator", essentially implemented via JavaScript, CSS and HTML. Its colors (and design, really) can be altered by over-writing its CSS IDs. You can use Chrome Dev Tools to debug, modify, experiment with, etc...

The IDs are (in Worklight 6.1 the source is in .wlapp\ ... \ worklight\worklight.css):

`#WLdialogContainer`, `#WLdialogOverlay`, `#WLdialog`, `#WLdialogTitle`, `#WLdialogBody`,  `#WLdialog button`